# How to change the Variation Label Name in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013

In SharePoint 2013 site settings for a site, I have created a variation label name as "en" as shown in the image below within a red box. Now I want to change it to "en-us".

[image]

But according to my research that it is not possible to change it in any way through OOTB. Is it possible to change it through any other means? (For example, PowerShell or other means.)

Comment: I'm not sure this question is programming related. Try the [Sharepoint](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) page, fully dedicated to Sharepoint.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change the variation label because if you change that you will break all links.
however i have found the below link:

[Change SharePoint Variation label display name](http://sharemypoint.in/2011/05/02/sharepoint-2010-error-changing-variation-label-display-name/)